# Draw a straight line between two points selected in a mouse down event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have code which draws a line as I move my mouse while clicking the mouse (mousedown event and mousemove event).

I also want a straight line to be drawn from the beginning of the point (where I first clicked the point, mousedown event) to the end (where I lift the mouse event, mouseup event).

```js
(function() {
      var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
      var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
      canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
      canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

      var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      
      var last_mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      /* Mouse Capturing Work */
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      }, false);


      /* Drawing on Paint App */
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
      }, false);

      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
      }, false);

      var onPaint = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
      };
    }());
```

```css
#sketch{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="sketch">
  <canvas id="paint">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a codepen ?

Comment: Better yet, put it in a snippet in the question so we don't have to go off-site

Answer (score 5):

You want to store the coordinates of the `mouseDown` event and then use them to draw a single line to the coordinates of the `mouseUp` event. I modified your code to show a way that can be done:

```js
(function() {
      var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
      var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
      canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
      canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

      var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };
      
      var last_mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      /* Mouse Capturing Work */
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      }, false);


      /* Drawing on Paint App */
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        initialPoint = {x:mouse.x, y:mouse.y}
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
      }, false);

      canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        drawStraightLine()
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
      }, false);

      var onPaint = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
      };
      
      let initialPoint
      const drawStraightLine = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF000077";
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }());
```

```css
#sketch{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="sketch">
  <canvas id="paint" />
</div>
```

`initialPoint` is the mouse position when the button is pressed and `drawStarightLine()` is the method executed when said button is released. Also added different colors to the lines to make it obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another position object eg

```
  const mouseDownAt = {x: 0, y: 0};
```

Then when the mouse down event happens record that position

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {

    mouseDownAt.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseDownAt.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);
```

On the mouse up event draw the closing line

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    lastMouse.x = mouse.x;
    lastMouse.y = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    // if mouse has moved?? draw the last little bit
    if (mouse.x !== last_mouse.x || mouse.y !== last_mouse.y) {
         onPaint();
    }

    // set the end position
    lastMouse.x = mouse.x;
    lastMouse.y = mouse.y;

    // use the mouse down at pos as the new position
    mouse.x = mouseDownAt.x;
    mouse.y = mouseDownAt.y;

    // draw the line
    onPaint();

    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
  }, false);
```

BTW I am not sure if you know that using `closePath` as you do will render the path segment twice and will reduce the quality of the line (too strong alphas on the anti aliasing) .  `closePath` is like `lineTo` (draws a line segment) and not related to `ctx.beginPath`

```
  function onPaint () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(lastMouse.x, lastMouse.y);  // after beginPath lineTo is the same
                                             // moveTo
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  };
```